# PHP parse MYSQL after comma and output to html table

Tags: php, mysql

Thank you all for you help! I received some phenomenal help about 17 days ago which saved my ***!. I am still learning PHP and have run across a new problem. I have a MYSQL database field called "Tracking" this is a long text field in which we want to input tracking numbers (for shipping) separated by commas . We ship some times 20-50 individual boxes in the same order.

The following script outputs to an HTML table the number of boxes being shipped (EX Box 1 of 12, Box 2 of 12...etc) and then the value of the tracking number field. I need to modify it so it parses at the "comma" in the Tracking field and includes the tracking number for each box. So Box 1: Tracking Number "take first tracking number and end at comma", So Box 2: Tracking Number "take second tracking number and end at comma"....etc...does this make sense?

Please provide whatever help possible, would greatly be appreciated!

Script:

```
    <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('***','***','***','***');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"db116223_wmi");
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_purchase_order WHERE purchase_order_id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
for ($i=0; $i<$row['product_quantity']; $i++) {
$my_val=1;
$x += 1;

echo "<table>";

echo "<tr>";

echo  "<td width=400><br>Box $x of ". $row['product_quantity'] ." Tracking Number:". $row['Tracking'] ."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

JB

Comment: I believe you are looking for the explode(); method. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php. EDIT: explode your string of tracking numbers off of your delimiter ',' and loop through your new array.

Comment: You may also want to look at the structure of a relational database like MySQL. Comma separating values like that defeats the purpose. Making another table like tbl_purchase_order_tracking_number with relation back to the tbl_purchase_order table makes issues like these much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jjonesdesign mentioned, you need to use explode to break the tracking number field up at each comma. explode creates an array of values, each split out of the Tracking field. Look below for the solution:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('***','***','***','***');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"db116223_wmi");
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_purchase_order WHERE purchase_order_id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$myTracking = explode(',',$row['Tracking']); // get an array of tracking numbers. Array element starts with 0
for ($i=0; $i<$row['product_quantity']; $i++) {
$my_val=1;
$x += 1;


echo "<table>";

echo "<tr>";

echo  "<td width=400><br>Box $x of ". $row['product_quantity'] ." Tracking Number:".  $myTracking[$i] ."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOR in /nfs/c08/h03/mnt/116223/domains/woodsmansinternational.com/html/web/tnemail.php on line 17 ............can u help?

Comment: Think just missing semi colon on line 16

Comment: added semi colon to line 16 and worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Read this post if your trying to output multiple tracking numbers or multiple shipping labels. I have used the same code for both. These guys are massively helpful.

Comment: Can you accept my answer, if you are satisfied, so the question does not remain marked as unanswered.